# How can I make sure Firestore security rules only accept Firestore Timestamps and not Javascript Dates

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to validate my inputs as part of my firestore rules.

Say I have a user doc that's a simple object which holds a Firestore Timestamp and the doc id is the uid.  I'm writing unit tests for my rules and want to distinguish between a valid one like this:

```
{ creationDate: FirestoreTimestamp.fromDate(new Date()) }
```

and an invalid one like this:

```
{ creationDate: new Date() }
```

My `firestore.rules` has this rule:

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow create: if (creationDate != null && creationDate is timestamp)
}
```

I'm writing unit tests to validate my rules and want to make sure Firestore Timestamps are the only valid input.

So I wrote a unit test that's expected to fail where we assign a different kind of time value to that field:

```
it('Fails if creationDate is not a Firestore timestamp', async () => {
                // Arrange
                const authedUser = testEnv.authenticatedContext(myId);
                const db = authedUser.firestore();
                const docRef = doc(db, 'users', myId);
                const docData = { dateCreated: new Date()};

                // Act & Assert
                await assertFails(setDoc(docRef, docData));
});
```

But it doesn't work.  When I run the test I get the error `Error: Expected request to fail, but it succeeded.`

Comment: "want to make sure Firestore Timestamps are the only valid input"  The question you'll want to ask yourself is: why? E.g. if you want the timestamp to be specified with nanosecond precision, then *that* is something you can try to validate in your rules.

Comment: I don't care about nanosecond precision.  I'm trying to guard against errors in the client code if it receives unexpected data from the db.  The client expects this field to have type Firestore Timestamp.  If a javascript Date is interchangeable with that, then cool. But it doesn't seem like that's something I can guarantee.  Firestore Timestamp isn't a descendant of Date.

Comment: General comment: I would not trust any timestamp coming from client. If you want the date the doc has been created better to use the built in `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and validate it in the rules with `creationDate  == request.time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The client expects this field to have type Firestore Timestamp.

If you pass either a `Timestamp` or a `Date` value to Firestore, it'll be stored as a `Timestamp` value. So this code that you give:

```
creationDate: FirestoreTimestamp.fromDate(new Date())
```

Has the same result as:

```
creationDate: new Date()
```

---

If you want the value to be stored with nanosecond precision, you should use:

```
creationDate: FirestoreTimestamp.now()
```

---

If you retrieve the value from a Timestamp field, it'll be returned as a `Timestamp` object that you can then get a `Date` value from if needed.

So even if you passed in a `Date` object initially, the value you get back from the database will be a `Timestamp` object.